# Deleting Records in database through kafka jdbc connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect Kafka connector with database using confluent kafka jdbc connector.

I can do insert and update the records from one database to another, but when I try to delete the records, the deleted records are not reflecting into target db. I mean synchronization of records(deleted records) are not deleted from target database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to until this gets merged

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/pull/282

Comment: thanks cricket_007.
then, Is there any alternative way to work with deletions?

Comment: Other than taking this PR and building the code yourself? Or writing your own separate consumer to listen for nullable record values? Not that I'm aware of